# click elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with click event. click to another element with event(click), doesn't count like click elsewhere. I want active one element or none.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WP4RH/

code:

```
   $('span').click(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     if($this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.removeClass('active')}
     else $this.addClass('active');

     $('div').click(function(){                        
        if (!$this.has(this).length) {                                 
             $this.removeClass('active');                            
        }          
     });
     return false;
   });
```

Comment: I wish I could grasp your question...what is the end result you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this at the beginning of your `span` event handler:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wuy4V/)

This is assuming that you want multiple clicks on the same span to retain `active`. If you don't want that, then let me know and I can modify the code.
​

Comment: @VIDesignz ... That was not intentional.. let me rephrase.. You may want to move that div click handler outside span click handler to avoid binding handler on every click.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, You should move the div handler outside and then `removeClass` based on div element.

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parent().find('span').removeClass('active');   
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('active');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WP4RH/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the toggle-off functionality when the `span` itself has been clicked, then you can use the following. Also, note that you're binding an event handler *each time a span is clicked*.

http://jsfiddle.net/WP4RH/7/

```
$("span").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("span").removeClass("active");  // remove from other spans
    $(this).toggleClass("active");  // toggle this span
    return false;
});
​
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).find("span").removeClass("active");  // remove from all spans
});
```

Comment: is there any chance, do this separately for each element? i don't want to search in throughout document and removeclass from all specific(class, name, ...) elements. my example was just illustration.

Comment: i dont know. therefore the question and therefore i use click in click in my example.

Comment: @Moriarty: I don't know what you mean. To me it seems my code fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind a click handler inside a click handler, just check if the target is the div or the span inside the click handler instead. Also, when adding the `active` class to `this`, just remove it on any sibling span :

```
$('span').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('span').removeClass('active');
});

$('div').on('click', function(e){                        
    if (e.target == this) $('span').removeClass('active');                            
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WP4RH/8/)
    ​